# Simple memory game

Tags: jquery, memory, visibility, hidden

I have modified this memory game to the way I want it. My problem is I'm trying to figure out how to make the images visible from the beginning when the game starts, i.e. I don't want the images hidden at all. I want all the other features, just not the lack of visibility.

Any tips on have I can change it?

```
var BoxOpened = "";
var ImgOpened = "";
var ImgFound = 0;

var Source = "#boxcard";

var ImgSource = [
  "http://img5.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992640c06707c66a5c0b08a2549c69745dc2c.png",
  "http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699263b01721074bf094aa3bc695aa19c8d573.png",
  "http://img6.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/17699262833250fa3063b708c41042005fda437d.png",
];


function OpenCard() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    if ($("#" + id + " img").is(":hidden")) {
        $(Source + " div").unbind("click", OpenCard);

        $("#" + id + " img").slideDown('fast');

        if (ImgOpened == "") {
            BoxOpened = id;
            ImgOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
            }, 300);
        } else {
            CurrentOpened = $("#" + id + " img").attr("src");
            if (ImgOpened != CurrentOpened) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#" + id + " img").slideUp('fast');
                    $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").slideUp('fast');
                    BoxOpened = "";
                    ImgOpened = "";
                }, 400);
            } else {
                $("#" + id + " img").parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
                $("#" + BoxOpened + " img").parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
                ImgFound++;
                BoxOpened = "";
                ImgOpened = "";
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(Source + " div").bind("click", OpenCard)
            }, 100);
        }
        Counter++;
        $("#counter").html("" + Counter);

        if (ImgFound == ImgSource.length) {
            $("#counter").prepend('<span id="success">You Found All Pictues With </span>');
        }
    }
}

$(function() {

for (var y = 1; y < 3 ; y++) {
    $.each(ImgSource, function(i, val) {
        $(Source).append("<div id=card" + y + i + "><img src=" + val + " />");
    });
}
    $(Source + " div").click(OpenCard);
});
```

See my jsfiddle for the complete code http://jsfiddle.net/NvkQw/

Comment: So you want all the images to initially be visible, but aside from that, the functionality should remain the same? In other words, once you start to click, the images should then disappear and stay hidden until you click on a box?

Comment: No, the must always be visible. This is a very, very simple memory game :)

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NvkQw/1/?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `#boxcard div img` as follows:

```
#boxcard div img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```